# How do I make my python program read a text file and specific lines?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that uses a text file to help display information when the program is running.

```
text_file = open ("Solution.txt","r") 
print text_file.readline()
print text_file.readline()
print text_file.readline()
text_file.close()
```

For some reason an invalid syntax appears on the lines following the first line of code. I really need this to work, so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: The suspicion is that you are using the Python 2 `print` statement in Python 3, where you should use the `print()` *function*: `print(text_file.readline())`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**:

```
print(test_file.readline())
```

I don't know what version of python you're using, but the print statement was changed to a function in python 3. The line you wrote was syntactically correct, which leads me to believe that the version of python you're using is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading lines with a for loop.

```
>>> with open("text.txt") as f:
...     for line in f:
...             print(line)
...
this is a line

this is another line

this is the third line
```

Or you can use `.readline()` :

```
>>> f = open("text.txt")
>>> f.readline()
'this is a line\n'
>>> f.readline()
'this is another line\n'
>>> f.readline()
'this is the third line'
>>> f.readline()
''
>>>
```

In your example if it is giving you syntax error, try using parenthesis in your `print` statement, you're probably using python3? Otherwise the code looks okay.
EDIT: If you're using `.readline()`, if the file runs out of lines it will print `''`.